# How can I remove characters around words?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to remove all characters that are not alphabetical from the beginning and end of each word.  For example:

> --Hello& World-@  1234...

Should look like:

> Hello World   1234

I tried `replaceAll`, but I have no idea how many different characters I need to remove or what those characters are.  I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
word = resultString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_0-9|$a-zA-Z_0-9]|^-|$-|^--|$--|^---|$---|\\$", "");
```

There were still words that showed up with dashes.

Is there another way to do this without using `replaceAll`?

Comment: if you want to delete special characters "from the beginning and end of each word", then be careful not to delete them INSIDE words, like "@" and "." characters inside email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be strict, all the answers don't solve **exactly** what the author asked. The problem is that they all will delete special characters **even inside words, and not only "from the beginning and end of each word"**.

Here is the code which fixes it:

```
String str = "--Hello& World-@ 1234...  my email is me@example.com";

// Analyzing every word     
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
String regex = "^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
String result = "";

for (String word : words) {
    result += word.replaceAll(regex, "") + " ";             
}

System.out.println(result); // gives "Hello World 1234 my email is me@example.com "
```

Regex `"^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` explanation:

`^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches one or more special characters at the beginning of the word

`|` OR

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$` one or more special characters at the end of the word.

You can modify the regex in order NOT TO DELETE the `,.!?:;` or other meaningful characters at the end of a word.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resultString = resultString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9_\\s]","");
```

This will replace everything except letters, numbers, underscores and spaces.

> Input: "--Hello& World-@ 1234..."
>
> Output: "Hello World 1234"

If you don't want to keep underscores in the string change the pattern to `[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]`.

Comment: but this will also delete special characters INSIDE words, which was not the goal.

Comment: Thats not what OP seems to be asking for though. Care to explain why you think otherwise? From the sample I suspect OP is saying that there may be special characters between 2 words but input like H#$ello W&/orld is not possible.

Comment: We surely need OP to clarify his needs, because i, for instance, based my answer upon the exact phrase "remove ... **from the beginning and end of each word**" , that's all. then, of course, he may want to do what you are suggesting, but in his example he didn't have any special characters inside words, as there was a space between `--Hello&` and `World-@`. I mean, he probably never has in his data things like emails. Then my suggestion is wrong, and your simple regex works perfectly. But i relied just on the way he formulated his question

Comment: @DenisFLASH Yes, I agree. Both of us are right from our respective points of view, so OP is the one to help us resolve the matter!

Comment: And yes, the question himself is called "How can I remove characters **around** words?"

Comment: exactly. But it's good that he could have some options. Probably, either approach will be used for him in some other case

Comment: Thanks DenisFLASH!  I forgot to add that the characters must stay within the words.  I edited my example.  

    Input: "--Hel-lo& Wo&rld-@ 12--34..."

    Output: "Hel-lo Wo&rld 12--34"

Comment: @user3889972 you are welcome. thanks to shree.pat18 as well, for a fruitful discussion

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]","")
```

without the underscore, as the OP mentioned he wanted to remove all characters that are not alphabetical from the beginning and end of each word

Input:

```
--Hello& World-@ 1234...
```

Output:

```
Hello World 1234
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028416/2416174) fails when there is an underscore in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
It replaces the characters other than letters or words,

```
word = resultString.replaceAll("[^\\w]", " ");
```

and output will be

Hello World 1234